# How to get article title where category id=8 in joomala

Tags: php, joomla

I tried to get articles titles where category id = 8.

here is the code i used.

```
$catID = 8;
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT title FROM #__content WHERE catid = ".$catID);
$catDesc = $db->loadResult();
echo $catDesc;
```

it display only **one** title which category id=8.

i want to display all the titles which category id = 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code as below:

```
$catID = 8;
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT title FROM #__content WHERE catid = ".$catID);
$catDesc = $db->loadObjectList();

var_dump($catDesc);
```

Use [`loadResult()`](http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase#loadResult.28.29) when you expect just a single value back from your database query.

[`loadObjectList()`](http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase#loadObjectList.28.29) returns an indexed array of PHP objects from the table records returned by the query.